# How do I secure my iOS app so that API calls cannot be made via web browser?

Tags: php, ios, json

I have built my first iOS app in Swift but I am concerned that is massively open to security issues.

When my app makes an API call and JSON request it does so in the following way:

```
let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.wyz.co.uk/xyz/myScript.php?");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "community_id=\(comIds[communityId!])&user_id=\(playerId!)&email=\(email!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
```

As you can see, currently there is nothing stopping anyone posting a string directly to a web browser (as I have done so myself in testing my JSON's) and making calls to the database and possibly doing damage.

How do I now go about making my app secure to stop any potential leakages etc? For instance, at one point it errored and brought up the connection details for my database including password! Not Good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for swift, but on the PHP side, I would:

1) Ensure that your App only communicates with the server over an HTTPS connection (you're sending data over an insecure/http connection currently)

2) Include a unique API key with your request. The key could be unique to the app, or unique to the user (look at how API providers do this, Google Maps API for instance). The server would then have to evaluate the API Key first to determine how it should respond to the request.

3) If you do this without HTTPS, then anyone monitoring the users connection can retrieve the API key that was transmitted and you're back to square 1.

Comment: Thanks Lucas that's really helpful - i didn't know where to start